# Find slot of private variable

Tags: solidity, storage, foundry, state-variable, slots

How do I find the slot of a private variable?

I know that Foundry has the method `stdstorage.sig()`, but that only works for variables with public getters, so private ones are out of scope.

Thanks!

Comment: You can use this https://www.npmjs.com/package/hardhat-storage-layout

Comment: Working on foundry, but thanks for the HH reply. @ZartajAfser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forge provides the [`inspect`](https://book.getfoundry.sh/reference/forge/forge-inspect) command to get specialized information about a smart contract.

Printing a contract's storage layout is achieved via:

```
forge inspect <Contract> storage --pretty
```

Note that `<Contract>` is the path to the contract's file plus the contract's name, eg `src/Counter.sol:Counter`.

The `--pretty` flag prints the storage layout in a more readable format. Without it, the command outputs the storage layout in json format.

Comment: How do you feed the address of an already deployed contract to the `inspect` command? Don't see the flag for it in the docs

Comment: If the contract is verified on etherscan, you can use `cast etherscan-source <address> --chain <chainId>`. See [here](https://book.getfoundry.sh/reference/cast/cast-etherscan-source) for more info.

Comment: That worked! Thanks.

Comment: also you can use services like https://evm.storage/ for deployed contracts

Comment: While external services like [evm.storage](https://evm.storage) can be used, keep in mind that they only support a subset of EVM chains. Foundry itself is chain-independent and the above proposed solution works for every EVM chain. However, the etherscan trick also only works for EVM chains with an Etherscan instance.